Can I delete a certain character from a JList?
First of all, English isn't my native tongue. So sorry in adavance for any mistakes!
For a project of mine I want to have a list with numbers the user decides to put in, and all of these numbers get a euro sign attached to it.
Now my problem is that I also need those numbers later for an equation, obviously without the euro sign. So, is there a way to turn those numbers into double but at the same time have the € be deleted?
If not I'll just scratch the idea of adding the euro sign in general, but it would be nice to have that in my list.
I tried searching online too, but maybe I couldn't find anything because I phrased it weirdly. Hopefully I worded all of this, so that it was understandable enough.
Thank you in advance!

It is "\u20AC" in Unicode.

You want to parse a String Object that represents currency.  Comments and answers to this question might help. If you need more help, try using a web search on "java parse currency string"

Does this answer your question? Parsing a currency String in java

I had to fix something like that many years ago. Don't parse floating point data from strings in a UI list. Instead use a Java list with the numbers as the model to feed your list and your computations. And for the love of goodness, never use floating point data types for currency data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency. Use BigDecimal.
